# curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash is asking for a Uri

Tags: laravel, curl, uri

When if follow the Laravel getting started docs it says to use

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

But it then asks me for a URI which the Laravel documentation does not tell me about.

If I try and put in something like:

```
d:laravel-test
```

The console comes back saying

```
Cannot recognize "D:laravel-test" as a System.Uri due to a format error.
```

I'm quite new to web development so please go easy on me.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: `d:laravel-test` would have to be `d:\laravel-test` though -  to make it a valid uri.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Laravel and Powershell

Comment: I'm having this same problem.

`curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

gives me

`cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri:`

Laravel docs don't have any information on this and several Google searches have given me zero answers.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the build command from a linux (Bash) command line, not the powershell.

1. In the Windows command line (powershell), navigate to the folder where your Laravel projects are to be stored.

   C:\Users\username>cd PATH TO FOLDER
2. Open the windows subsystem for linux by typing 'wsl' at the prompt

   C:\Users\username\path to folder>wsl  (This part isn't clear in the docs)
3. This will open the Linux/BASH command line where you should paste the Laravel curl build command

username@computer:/filepath$ curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash

This will launch the installation.  Note that it will take a long time the first time but will be much faster the next time.  The Docker environment will continue to run in this terminal.

Not an expert but this worked for me.

curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash